# EmberJS redirect when no subroute specified

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a set of nested routes and templates that I'd like to auto-select the first model if no sub-routes are specified. The route structure is:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('sales', function () {
    this.route('orders', function () {
      this.route('order', { path: ':order_id' });
    });  
  });
});
```

If the user hits `sales.orders` then they should be redirected to the first order on the `sales.orders` model. Making this work is no problem. The issue comes when the user hits `sales/orders/:order_id` No matter what `:order_id` is the user is always redirected to the first order in the `orders` array.

I'm currently performing the redirect in the `setupController`hook of the `SalesOrders` route as I have some sorting on the controller that needs to be in place prior to redirecting.

```
App.SalesOrdersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('order');
  },

  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    var firstObject = controller.get('sortedContent').get('firstObject');
    this.transitionTo('sales.orders.order', firstObject);
  }
});

App.SalesOrdersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['orderNumber:desc'],
  sortedContent: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProperties')
});
```

I have [a jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yabuwuhore/3/edit) that shows my issue.

Hitting [any](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yabuwuhore/3/#/sales/orders/1) [specific](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yabuwuhore/3/#/sales/orders/2) [order](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yabuwuhore/3/#/sales/orders/3) will always redirect to the first order in the array (4 in this case).

I need it to keep the deep linked url and only redirect when no order is specified.

I feel like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508979/how-to-redirect-to-a-nested-dynamic-segments-in-emberjs) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013823/emberjs-only-redirect-to-default-route-if-no-subroute-is-specified) are both similar to what I'm trying to do except neither addresses auto-selecting the first item if no sub-routes are specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the redirect in your SalesOrdersIndex route. The additional index route of each route will only be created when it matches the complete URL mapping. So for any url that isn't exactly "sales/orders" it will not be created. Just what you want.

```
App.SalesOrdersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    this.controllerFor('salesOrders').set('model',model);
   var firstObject = this.controllerFor('salesOrders').get('sortedContent').get('firstObject');
    this.transitionTo('sales.orders.order', firstObject);
  }  
});
```

jsbin: [4](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pavomo/2/#/sales/orders/4) [3](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pavomo/2/#/sales/orders/3) [2](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pavomo/2/#/sales/orders/2) [1](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pavomo/2/#/sales/orders/1) [redirect to 4](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pavomo/2/#/sales/orders)

Comment: @bavo-van-get you nailed it! I tweaked the routes in my app (slightly more complicated than my example) and it's working perfectly! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to check the transition on the afterModel hook and redirect *if* the user is trying to access the `sales.orders.index` route.

Something like this:

```
afterModel: function(model, transition){
  if (transition.targetName === "sales.orders.index"){
    var first = model.objectAt(0);
    this.transitionTo('sales.orders.order', first);
  }
}
```

[Here's an example.](http://jsbin.com/layuliheda/1/edit)

That won't work with `setupController` as the `setupController` hook does not have access to the transition. In your case, since you just want to sort, you could do something like:

```
var first = model.sortBy('orderNumber').reverse().objectAt(0);
```

As far as I know, `setupController` is called after both `redirect` and `afterModel` so I'm not sure it's possible to get the sorted content from the controller through the `afterModel` and `redirect` hooks.